# cannot push local branch because of a huge file in history

Tags: git, github

I've a problem with Git, I work locally on my brand new branch, never pushed. I have in my branch history a big file (200Mb). the error is the following:

> remote: error: File src/test/resources/data/file.big is 204.65 MB; this exceeds GitHub's file size limit of 100.00 MB

That's my beanches situation:

```
-main-
 \-[branch_x]-commit#1-commit#2-commit#3-commit#4
```

I've commited the big file at commit#1, now I'm in commit#4; i replace the big file with another one, much smaller, but it's still in git history, so I cannot push my branch and my work ! Someone can help me pls with a smooth solution ? I don't want to wipe local repository and manually reaplace files, it's a lot of modification, something may go wrong !

I read something here on Stack, but I cannot fix it, someone can help me pls ? really appreciated !

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgit%5D+remove+large+file+history